# Unable to get SDK tools only installer

Tags: sdk, appium

I m new to appium and I m following the beginners tutorials available on the net. I came across the Installation guide and it requires me to Download "SDK tools only  installer" from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Other) and continue with the setup, but currently there is no such file available. The only thing available is the windows package and when I download that, it contains some different files. It does not have the sdk manager application in. Anyone who can guide me to the latest SDK Installation , or mind to help me out clarify the confusion.Should we go with Android studio installation for SDK installation or is there a manual way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried this couple of months back, and I think the process got changed with the latest version of Android SDK. There are 2 options -

1. Download the command line tools (given at the end of the page). This method might be bit confusing to follow for beginners. You can give it a try if you are comfortable with it.
2. Download Android Studio and then check the SDK tools there (I found this easier to follow and setup).

If you wish to use the 2nd approach, then you can check this guide - [Step by Step Appium Tutorial Guide](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-tutorial/)

Comment: Yes I also downloaded the android studio and working on the installation, Thanks for that link Anish, will try that and get back..

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement it will be update, after installation just follow it's instruction, as per your package requirement it will be updated(like for 4.4,6.0...)

Your required package has been updated after installation of SDK, and any supporting package is not providing directly .

Comment: I m trying to install but I cannot find  SDK download in the Android developer site..